# Data processing in JSON

Tags: json, go-gin

the structure comes to me for updating, the problem is that I do not know how to understand when the structure field has the value nil, because the user did not pass it, and when nil, because the user decided to update this field

I'm processing fields via reflect and I can't figure out when we passed null and when it's the default